# Regarding the expected value, what's the meaning of E(-5X) and E(X+Y)?

Tags: expected-value

if  X∼N(2,1) then the expected value of −5X ? E(−5X) = -5E(X)

if Y~N=(4,1) then the expected value of X+Y? E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)

Can you please tell me what is the meaning of multiplying or summing expected values ?

Comment: What exactly is unclear for you?

Comment: I understand that the expected value in a normal distribution is the mean (I think of it as the center of distribution). But, in such example E(-5X) I don't understand : Is it the center of a new distribution after multiplying every value by -5 or What? . I can't imagine it also in E(X,Y). Is it that we created two distribution and the expected value is the center of the two distributions ?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly like you said. E(-5X) is expected value of X multiplied by -5, E(X + Y) is expected value of sum of X and Y. Have you checked: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value ?

Comment: This question seems clear enough to me. The key is that if $X$ is a random variable, then $-5X$ is *also* a random variable, and has its own mean. However, the title of the question (currently "What's the importance of understanding the properties of the 'Expected value'?") currently does not seem to align well with the question asked below it. I suggest editing the title to make it match closer to the actual question

Comment: The expected value is not in general the "center" of the distribution, even though it is for a Normal random variable.

Comment: I tried to understand it using R and posted an answer.

Comment: An expected value, by definition, is a number. You are therefore asking what it means to multiply and add numbers!  Obviously there's something else of concern to you--but what are you really trying to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you roll the dice, if you roll a one you win one euro, if you roll a two then you win 2 euro, ... if you roll six than you win six euro.

If the dice is fair then the probability to roll a one is 1/6, the same for rolling a two, ... the same for rolling a six.

So for a dice we have $P(X=1)=P(X=2)=\dots = P(X=6)=1/6$. If you get one euro if you throw 1, two euro if you get two, ... then your ''expected win'' is $1 \times 1/6 + 2 \times 1/6 + \dots + 6 \times 1/6=3.5$ which is the expected value of $1X$, i.e. E(1X)=E(X)=3.5$, one because you get 1 euro for each dot that comes up.

If you get 1000 euro for each dot that comes up, then you have to compute the expected values of $1000X$ to compute your expected profit, i.e. $E(1000X)=1000E(X)=3500$.

For sums it is simular, but you use two dice, one with an outcome X, the other one with an outcome Y.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the meaning of E(-5X), I used the following R code:

```
r=rnorm(100,5,5)
library(sm)
d=data.frame(r,-5*r)
colnames(d)=c('newr','oldr')

library(tidyr)
do=gather(d)

sm.density.compare(do[,2],as.factor(do[,1]))

abline(v=5)
text(28,.06,'old center')

abline(v=-25)
text(-50,.06,'new center')
#new mean        
mean(-5*r)
```

[image: old distribution with X and new distribution after multiplying X by -5]

To understand E(X+Y), I used the following R code:

```
dist1=rnorm(100,5,5)
dist2=rnorm(100,4,4)
#expected value of E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)=5+4=9
XplusY=dist1+dist2
d=data.frame(dist1,dist2,XplusY)
colnames(d)=c('dist1','dist2','newdist')

library(tidyr)
do=gather(d)
sm.density.compare(do[,2],as.factor(do[,1]))

abline(v=9) #the center of multiplying values of two dists
mean(XplusY)  #approximately 9
```

[image]